# Token matching order in PLY

Tags: ply

I have a parser written in PLY that has the following token definition

```
def t_COMMAND(t):
    r'create|show'
    return t

def t_SCOPE(t):
    r'user|domain'
    return t

def t_STRING(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_@\*\.]*'
    return t
```

I am trying to parse the following string

```
show user where created_on = foo
```

Here is my grammar

```
S:COMMAND SCOPE FILTER;
FILTER:WHERE EXP |;
EXP:STRING OP STRING
...
```

I get a syntax error at the `created_on` token, probably because it gets matched as a `COMMAND` rather than `STRING`

Is there a way to make PLY take the largest possible match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found two possible approaches

- User a reserved words tuple and append it with the token list as in [Specification of tokens](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6)
- If possible, add quotes to the `STRING` as `'[a-zA-Z_@\*\.]*'`, so that it can be distinguished from `COMMAND`

I chose the second approach, as I have a lot of so called reserved words.

Comment: You can "accept" your own answer to show the problem has been solved.